# Less so than vs. much less

Tags: sentence-meaning, synonyms

are the following sentences **synonymous** with each other?(Google's example sentence)

> "What woman would consider a date with him, **less so than** a marriage?"

To

> "What woman would consider a date with him, **much less** a marriage?"

Comment: The first sentence is ungrammatical and doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I have just slipped that in(less so than) to compare if that is also possible... seems like it is incorrect.